# How to embed substituion variable into string in "psql"

Tags: variables, substitution, psql

I'm calling a bash script which prepares some directories etc. 
At some point it also calls a psql script something like this:

```
psql $PSQL_LOGIN -v SERVER=$SERVER
```

So far so good.

The sql that I want to execute is something like this:

```
select 'wget :SERVER.xxxx.com?geoX=id1&geoY=id2' 
from table1 where id1 > zzz;
```

What I expect out of this is a string that looks like

```
wget test.xxx.com?geoX=yyy&geoY=qqq
```

In oracle I could do something like

```
select 'wget' || :SERVER '.xxx.com?geoX='|| id1 || etc etc
```

But I cannot make it work in postgres when it should be embedded in a string
I've tried to escape the ' and withoud but so far no luck.
Anybody got any ideas?

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html#AEN88056

Comment: I cant really find a solution from this link. Its not the actual sustitution that troubles me, its the substitution into a string.

Comment: Maybe it simply isn't possible in psql ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer to this question.
When calling from the shell script, its in the shell script itself that 
the escaping must be done. So instead of the above i should do the calling like this :

```
psql $PSQL_LOGIN -V SERVER="'$SERVER'"
```

that is double quote and single quote.
Then the sql file can be done the same way as in Oracle :

```
select 'wget' || :SERVER '.example.com?geoX='|| id1 || ' etc
```